# Regular Expressions | Delete words on multiple lines before a given word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I scraped several articles from a website and now I am trying to make the corpus more readable by deleting the first part from the text scraped.
The interval that it should be deleted is within the tag `<p>Advertisement` and the final tag `</time>` before the article starts. As you can see, the regular expression should delete several words on multiple lines. I tried with the DOTALL sequence but it wasn't successful.

This is my first attempt:

```
import re

text='''
<p>Advertisement</p>, <p class="byline-dateline"><span class="byline"itemprop="author creator" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">By <span class="byline-author" 
data-byline-name="MILAN SCHREUER" itemprop="name">MILAN SCHREUER</span> and </span><span class="byline" 
itemid="http://topics.nytimes.com/top/reference/timestopics/people/r/alissa_johannsen_rubin/index.html" 
itemprop="author creator" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a href="http://topics.nytimes.com/top/reference/timestopics/people/r/alissa_johannsen_rubin/index.html" 
title="More Articles by ALISSA J. RUBIN"><span class="byline-author" data-byline-name="ALISSA J. RUBIN" data-twitter-handle="Alissanyt" itemprop="name">ALISSA J. RUBIN</span></a></span><time class="dateline" content="2016-10-06T01:02:19-04:00" 
datetime="2016-10-06T01:02:19-04:00" itemprop="dateModified">OCT. 5, 2016</time>
</p>, <p class="story-body-text story-content" data-para-count="163" data-total-count="163">BRUSSELS — A man wounded two police officers with a knife in Brussels around noon on Wednesday in what the authorities called “a potential terrorist attack.”</p>, <p class="story-body-text story-content" 
data-para-count="231" data-total-count="394">The two officers were attacked on the Boulevard Lambermont in the Schaerbeek district, just north of the city center. A third police officer, who came to their aid, was also    injured. None of the three had life-threatening injuries.</p>
'''
my_pattern=("(.*)</time>") 
results= re.sub(my_pattern," ", text)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_pattern=("[\s\S]+\<\/time\>")
```

If you also want to delete also the following tag `</p>`, the comma `,` and the space, you can use this:

```
my_pattern=("[\s\S]+\<\/time\>[\s\S]\<\/p\>\,\s")
```

Comment: What if I want to leave out the first tag <p>Advertisement</p> and its attribute?

Comment: @M.Huntz You try something like this `(?<=\<\/p\>)[\s\S]+\<\/time\>` or this `(?<=\<\/p\>)[\s\S]+\<\/time\>[\s\S]\<\/p\>\,\s`  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/79n80Z/3